# Retrieve files deleted by command rm in terminal

Tags: data-recovery

Here's a summary: I was programming using java and accidentally, instead of using the rm *.class command in the command-line, I used rm *.java. It took me a lot of time to finish that code. I hope someone knows a way to retrieve those files. Please help me.