# Recover lost deleted json files on ubuntu 12.04 server?

Tags: 12.04, server

I have unknowingly deleted my folder containing json files using rm command on ubuntu 12.04 server. I tried using "scalpel" tool but it does not work for Json files. Is there any other way by which I may recover my lost data.

I also tries "testdisk" but it throws the error:

```
/proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs error
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve files deleted by command rm in terminal](http://askubuntu.com/questions/265991/retrieve-files-deleted-by-command-rm-in-terminal) and http://askubuntu.com/questions/150671/accidentally-deleted-a-folder

Answer (score 0):

You can try extundelete. If the data is important then create a disk image and a copy of that image and work on the imagecopy only. The more you try to recover data on a running system, the higher the chances are that you destroy the data that is left on the disk.